# DocuSign - 'JWT Grant' with non-admin user?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a DocuSign app that uses '*Auth Code Grant*' for individual users to create and send envelopes, and uses '*JWT Grant*' for polling and downloading signed documents (i.e., automated operations as [described by the documention](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/)).

All the examples and documentation I've encounter seem focused on using an admin/system account for JWT Grant, and specifically for impersonating users. I don't need user impersonation functionality in general.

I am currently using a regular (non-admin) user that is assigned a custom permission profile. The profile is simple with only the '*Allow view and manage envelope rights through API*' checked. This works in the dev sandbox. I have no problems polling or pulling documents with this user and JWT Grant.

- Is it acceptable to use a non-admin user for JWT Grant as in this instance?
- Can anyone possibly point me documentation surrounding using JWT Grant for automated processes that do not require heavy integration or admin-level access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, it is acceptable, I'm not aware of any reason it won't be.
- This [JWT Best Practices Guide](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-best-practice/) on the DocuSign Developer center. Not sure what else you may need, but feel free to ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the JWT Grant flow to impersonate account users who are not administrators. This is a common use case for JWT Grant.

Comment: Got it. It seemed like this would be common enough, but I wasn't completely clear on it. Most of the documentation for JWT Grant seems to be geared more toward larger integrations or those requiring impersonation for multiple users.